# how to access external php script from view page using ajax in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have php files which is outside of application folder. i have call those php script via ajax  script and save value in database. how to call like this

```
   $('#avatarModal').imgPicker({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>server/upload_avatar.php',
    max_file_size: 5000000,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

 $('#avatarModal').imgPicker({
    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>server/upload_avatar.php',
    max_file_size: 5000000,

</script>
```

To use `base_url` function

in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

> because Codeigniter load `base_url` path automatically.